# How to configure appium with serenity/js?

Tags: appium, serenity-js

can we setup Appium with serenity/JS to supports running tests on mobile devices for hybrid applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Protractor's responsibility to provide Serenity/JS with an instance of a browser, so it should be enough to configure Protractor to use Appium as per the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md#mobile-setup).

Hope this helps!

Jan